# How to get sorted values from n to n+m in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I know we can get top 5 sorted elements using the following formula:

```
sortn(sorting!A2:A,5)
```

## Question

- How to get sorted 5 to 10 elements?

I have shared the public spreadsheet here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10NzbtJhQj4hQBnZXcmwise3bLBIAWrE0qwSus_bz7a0/edit#gid=403955410

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a query:

```
=query(A:A,"select A where A is not null order by A  limit 5 offset 5",1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I've added a new sheet ("Erik Help") to your sample spreadsheet. You'll find the following array formula highlighted in bright green:

`=SORT(SORTN(SORTN(sorting!A2:A,10,0,1,1),5,0,1,0))`

The 10 represents the last element of range 5-10, while the 5 represents the first element of that range.

Essentially, this pulls everything up to the 10th element, flips it upside down, takes the bottom 5, then flips it right-side-up again.